# Cómo conectar cqlsh 5.0.1 y Cassandra 3.6 remotamente?

Tags: vagrant, cassandra

Tengo un nodo de cassandra en virtualbox con las siguientes configuraciones en cassandra.yaml:

```
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer
role_manager: CassandraRoleManager
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: localhost
rpc_port: 9160
```

Cuando accedo desde la máquina por cqlsh puedo conectar pero desde
el host esto no es posible, los puertos tienen un NAT así:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9042, host: 9042, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9160, host: 9160, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
```

[image: Conexión Local y Remota]

Answer (score 0):

Acorde con [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121904/cassandra-cqlsh-connection-refused) se debe colocar la IP en el cassandra.yaml
del rpc así:

rpc_address: 192.168.1.100

Esto generó otro error por el protocolo cql cql_verion "3.1.1"

[image: Error en version procolo cql]

Para conectarse se [forzó el uso del protocolo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002404/cassandra-cqlsh-unable-to-connect-to-any-servers?answertab=active#tab-top) a la versión 3.4.2

```
 cqlsh localhost 9042 -u usuario -p  xclave --cqlversion="3.4.2"
```

Los puertos se redireccionaron en Vagrant así:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.100"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9042, host: 9042, guest_ip: "192.168.1.100"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9160, host: 9160, guest_ip: "192.168.1.100"
```